# A certain class of representations

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gr.group-theory, harmonic-analysis, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $g$ be a non-identity element in a torsion-free amenable group, does there exist a finite-dimensional unitary representation $\pi$ with $\pi(g)\neq 1$?

(The word "finite-dimensional" was initially omitted: as mentioned in the comments the answer is a trivial "yes" then, by considering the left regular representation.)

Comment: What do you mean by the kernel of a representation?

Comment: And what do you mean by R(GxG) if only R(G) is given?

Comment: @ThiKu By the kernel of the representation $\pi$ I mean $\{g\in G: \pi(g)=0\}$. For the second question, these families of representations should be defined for all torsion-free amenable groups, so if we have $\mathbf R(G)$, so we do also have $\mathbf R(G\times G)$.

Comment: Can I take $R(H)$ to be the set of all unitary representations (say on a Hilbert space of sufficiently small cardinality) for all $H$?

Comment: Surely you want $\pi(g) = 1$, not $\pi(g) = 0$ ….

Comment: Anent @MatthewDaws's point, it seems that (2) is redundant; enlarging the class $\mathbf R$ does not destroy (1), so, if there is *any* class satisfying (1), then the class of *all* unitary representations certainly does.

Comment: @MatthewDaws Yes, if it satisfies both (1) and (2), does it?

Comment: @LSpice: You are right, it should be $\pi(g)=1$.

Comment: So in the end, it seems this question can be reduced to "Let $G$ be a torsion-free amenable group, and let $g \neq e \in G$; then is there some unitary representation $\pi$ such that $\pi(g) \neq 1$?"

Comment: @user44191  Yes, that's what it seems like to me.  The left-regular representation has this property...  And so the questions seems a bit trivial, unless some other property is meant?

Comment: So, for the new question: "yes" the left-regular representation has this property.

Comment: I have rolled this back to Version 4, even though the answer then turns out to be trivial as pointed out by others in comments, because the change made after version 4 is so drastic that it invalidates the efforts and responses of the existing comments. I suggest that if the OP is specifically interested in fin-dim reps he should post this as a new question, but perhaps more thought is needed about what exactly he is looking for (i.e. not such a vague fishing expedition)

Comment: Without any additional requirements on the representation, the answer to this question is positive for any locally compact group via the left-regular representation as mentioned above. The hypotheses about amenability and torsion-free are unnecessary.

Comment: @YemonChoi I don't agree (in general): this is precisely because the question (without "finite-dim") is trivial that it's been shortly answered in comments and not in an answer. I've resumed the amended question, while mentioning these comments. (By rolling back to an off-topic question, doomed to quick closure and subsequent deletion, don't you also "invalidate" the "efforts and responses of the existing comments"?

Comment: @YCor I see your point, but the OP and others of similar mathematical background and training have a habit of asking ill-posed questions and subsequently moving the goalposts in seemingly arbitrary ways. (I and others in my area end up refereeing the consequences of this attitude.) It is not clear to me that "fin-dim reps" was a well-thought out condition that the OP had in mind, or just a knee-jerk response of the form "oh my question has a trivial answer, well let me just add in another condition"

Comment: @YCor In other words, I am trying to promote behaviour where the OP and other users with similar habits **think harder** about the initial question they ask. If this means the closure (not necessarily deletion) of questions that were not sufficiently thought through, then I see this as a feature and not a bug of the mechanisms of this site. However, I will not pursue this particular case further :)

Comment: @YemonChoi I agree about the intention!

Comment: It is not appropriate to judge people simply. But we have to help the OP to come close to the question he has in mind. Few people do so, and sure @YCor is one of them, thank you Yevs. It is not my honor to win a badge, but to communicate with mathematicians is my honor.

Answer (score 1):

The buzzword to look for is "maximally almost periodic".  This is part of the theory of [Bohr Compactifications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr_compactification).  Start with a (locally compact) group $G$.  I do not believe amenability and (especially) torsion freeness has much if any baring on what following.

The Bohr Compactification is the maximal compact group $K$ for which there is a dense range homomorphism $\theta:G\rightarrow K$.  Any finite-dimensional unitary rep of $G$ factors through $\theta$ (by the representation theory of compact groups).  It follows that finite-dimensional unitary reps separate the points of $G$ if and only if $\theta$ is injective.  By definition, this means that $G$ is "maximally almost periodic" (MAP).  One can also construct $K$ using almost periodic functions, and here $G$ is MAP if and only if the almost periodic functions separate the points of $G$.

The Freudenthai-Weil theorem says that for connected locally compact groups, $G$ is MAP if and only if $G=\mathbb R^n \times L$ for some compact $L$.  Chapter 16 of Dixmier's book on $C^\ast$-algebras is a good source for all of this.

[Searching around MathOverFlow](https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=maximally+almost+periodic) will find [examples](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/177990/are-countable-fc-groups-maximally-almost-periodic) of groups which are not MAP.

Comment: The question is asked for discrete groups. In this case, one can still answer the question in the negative. For a finitely generated group, to be MAP is equivalent to being residually finite (and there are torsion-free solvable f.g. groups for which this fails).